# Google Docs API: Do document resource ID's ever change?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Is it wise to build a website like environment where all links are based on resource ID's from documents?
Did document ID's ever change in the past, can/will they in the future?

Past week we were surprised to see a collection where it looks like some ID's of documents had changed, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately they do, read about my experience here: google doc **[IDs aren't quite as immutable as made out to be...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14574833/1712120)**.

Answer (score 3):

The id is a unique, permanent identifier for the entry, so it should never change.

Comment: That's what I hoping to hear! --Thx!