# There is a possibility that the Google Docs ID is reused?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I have understood that this ID is unique on the link.

[Google Docs API: Do document resource ID's ever change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274319/google-docs-api-do-document-resource-ids-ever-change)

In addition I want to know is whether there is a possibility that the ID will be reused in the future.

(Example)

- FolderA (ID is A)  a user is created has been removed.
- Other users to create FolderB. There is a possibility of FolderB ID is A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, IDs are unique and permanent, so they never get reused.

Comment: I really appreciated your help!