# Google Drive SDK docid changed - How to relate documents stored by old docid to the new one?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-apps, google-drive-api

It appear that the docid's changed for all google drive documents on our google apps domain...

- **Will it change again?**
- **Why was it changed?**  (my google/yahoo/bing searches on this subject turn up nothing useful - is no one else experiencing this?  For me it seems to have happened at around Jan 16/17th)

And most importantly for now:

- **Is there a way to cross-reference all of the old docid's to the corresponding new docid's?**

Comment: Doc IDs shouldn't have changed by themselves. Do you have any sort of backup/restore process going on that may have deleted then recreated the docs? All files or just blobs/binaries? Have you checked the revision history to see if it is intact from before the change? If everything checks out and they are indeed the same files as before and not copies/recreations, please send me (sbazyl@goog**.com) the before & after IDs and your domain name so we can look into it.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your fast response!  This seems to be affecting all of our documents (we have over 600 presentations in drive) - I just checked 3 of them and they all have exactly 1 revision, the same date in each case (January 16, 2013).  Google Drive SDK is being used to download a PDF version of the presentations - download only though (PDF export), no uploading.  I'll send an email.

Comment: @SteveBazyl I have a somewhat related question, I'm trying to back-reference a `X-Document-ID` from an email back to a google drive file ID to validate the document came from our company.  The issue I'm seeing is that the doc-id from the email looks like: sJ9ysXtvFe5Ydxy3EkKCpeA, whereas the doc-id from a drive list looks like: 1ZepaYrd54iF9bu6NeasZ6gF_tOarsv418Q9CTNAqegQ, both are accepted via https://docs.google.com/document/d/[ID]/edit.  Is there a way to derive one from the other?

Answer (score 2):

Found out some more info. The root cause is a migration from the old presentation editor to the new one. The new editor has been the default for a while, but to complete switch over all the older presentations needed to be converted. For various technical reasons, it wasn't possible to do this without creating new file entries for each presentation. This happened once before about 6 months ago when the same thing was done for documents.

It is possible remap the IDs by checking the change feed. The delete & create will appear as separate events, but if you look for deletes followed by a create of a file with the same title you can build up a mapping of the file IDs. Not *entirely* foolproof, but its a one time operation.

So turns out IDs aren't quite as immutable as made out to be...

Comment: hmmm, that is bad news.  We have a lot of documents to go through, many of which may have the same title, so I'm not sure that will work (for us).  Are there any other options - e.g. is there some way I could detect a changed docid by attempting to download the old docid document and getting a redirect message?  For example in this function here in the ...

`    function downloadFile($service, $file) {...}`

... found here:  [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads?hl=en#examples)-- is there some way to map the old doc id to the new one by detecting a redirect here?